# Drupal 7.41 [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 19ms]

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, localhost, fedora, error-log

I'm trying to install Drupal locally on Fedora 22.

I've done all that **drupal.org/documentation/install** says to complete the installation but when I try to run Drupal it doesn't works.

On the URL I put: localhost/ and it works so it seems that I don't have any problem here, but when I write: localhost/drupal or localhost/drupal/install.php it doesn't works!

And everytime I get this error: GET http://localhost/drupal/install.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 19ms]

Does someone know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take a look at your apache or nginx logs (error logs) to see what is the problem. Some server configuration output the errors in a file "error_log" in the root of your Drupal installation.

http://www.codeasite.com/index.php/linux-a-apache/94-how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Nginx

Maybe some PHP extensions are missing. Check Drupal requirements : https://www.drupal.org/requirements